# Spring RestController ambiguous mapping error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm setting up a RestController in Spring, and I have an ambiguous mapping issue. I don't see how the last two methods are ambiguous, because the request mappings and method names are different. When I remove the method specification from the last method, the issue isn't there anymore.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class TagController {

    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/tag/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<TagList> getTagList() {
        TagList result = new TagList(tagService.list());
        return new ResponseEntity<TagList>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/tag/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addTag(@RequestBody AlterTagForm form) {
        try {
            tagService.addTag(form.getArticleId(), form.getTagName());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/tag/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> removeTag(@RequestBody AlterTagForm form) {
        try {
            tagService.removeTag(form.getArticleId(), form.getTagName());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

which results in this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'tagController' bean method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.example.article.controller.TagController.removeTag(com.example.admin.form.AlterTagForm)
to {[],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'tagController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.example.article.controller.TagController.addTag(com.example.admin.form.AlterTagForm) mapped.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `@RequestMapping` annotations you should set your paths using `value` properties. The `value` property determines the path your methods should handle, while the `name` property is just for identifying the mapping in the Spring environment.

Your methods `addTag()` and `removeTag()` are currently both mapped to the index path of the controller (`/`), and since they are similar in every way (method, produces, argument) except the name, Spring cries foul.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `RequestMapping` using `value` property.

Value property should be unique otherwise its gonna throw an exception. Right now in your code both method redirect to `/` by default.